# how to add dynamic items in a collection in javascript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, collections

i want to add number of elements in a collection in javascript,as doing in following vb's code

```
    Dim myList As New List(Of String)


    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 0 To rep_UnAssignComps.Items.Count
        myList.Add(i)
    Next
```

I want to compare this collection with a particular value.provide me syntax for comparing the value also. like

```
myList.Contains(val1)
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Not sure what you want to store in the collection but in java-script, you have two choices to achieve collections.

First is to use [arrays](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_array.asp). For example,

```
var arr = [];  // empty array
arr.push('A');
arr.push('B');
arr.push('C');
alert(arr.length); // alerts 3
alert(arr[1]);     // alerts B (zero based indexing)
```

To check if any element exists or not, you have to run a loop over an array comparing element at each index.

Another method will be using java-script object as hash table. Essentially, every java-script object can have multiple properties that are essentially name-value pairs. For example,

```
var o = { } // empty object
o["prop1"] = "A";   // Added property named prop1 with value "A"
o["prop2"] = "B";   // Added property named prop2 with value "B"
o["prop3"] = "C";   // Added property named prop2 with value "C"
alert(o["prop1"]);  // alerts A
alert(o.prop2);     // alerts B - notice alternate syntax
alert(o["prop4"]);     // alerts undefined - because we are accessing non-existent property
if (o["prop3"]) {
  alert("prop3 exists");  // to check for some property
}
for (p in o) {  // iterate all properties
  alert(p);     // alerts property name
  alert(o[p]);  // alerts property value
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `push` method http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_push.asp

Answer (score 0):

```
var myList = []
var i = 0;
```

**if "rep_UnAssignComps" is an array use for loop else use for in**

```
if (rep_UnAssignComps instanceof Array) {
    for (i = 0; i < rep_UnAssignComps.length; i++){
       myList.push(i);
    }
}else {
    for(var name in rep_UnAssignComps){
        if (rep_UnAssignComps.hasOwnProperty(name)){
            myList.push(i);
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

**To compare use:**

```
//Returns the first index at which a given element can be found in the array, or -1 if it is not present
myList.indexOf(val1);
```